# Mudar cores pie chart php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Boa tarde!
Estou a criar um gráfico circular, os dados eu busco da base de dados.
Porém não sei como se muda as cores dos setores do gráfico circular, para deixar mais claro vou mostrar aqui o que pretendo.

O código é o seguinte:

`include "../classif/BD/ligabd.php";
...`
`

```
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});;
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() 
  {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['classificacao','Number'],
    <?php
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
      echo "['".$row["classificacao"]."', ".$row["number"]."],";
    }
    ?>
    ]);
   var options = {
    title:'Classificações do refeitório', 
    is3D:true
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data,options);
}
```

Gráfico das classificações do refeitório
  
  

`

O output é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu pretendia era em vez de em "amarelo" estar a cor azul, a cor fosse amarelo, onde diz verde, em vez de ser vermelho que fosse verde, assim em diante...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens um [campo `colors` nas `options`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts).

Exemplo

```
var options = {
  // .. outras opcoes
  colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']
};

chart.draw(data, options);
```

Se não controlas a ordem dos dados mas queres que um item específico tenha uma certa cor, podes mudar o teu `while` um bocado.

```
<?php
$colors = [];
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  switch ($row['classificacao']) {
    case 'amarelo' : $colors[] = 'yellow'; break; // 'amarelo' deve ser o item que queres que seja amarelo. 'yellow' deve por o código da cor que queres
    case 'vermelho': $colors[] = 'red';    break;
    case 'azul'    : $colors[] = 'blue';   break;
  }
  echo "['".$row["classificacao"]."', ".$row["number"]."],";
}
?>
var options = {
  title:'Classificações do refeitório', 
  is3D:true,
  colors: <?php echo json_encode($colors) ?>
};
```

Comment: Mas como é que digo que quero que o vermelho seja a cor vermelha, amarelo cor amarelo, etc... ?

Comment: É a mesma ordem do que vai no `data`

Comment: Heheh, obrigada!

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo de como podes controlar as cores se nao controlas a ordem do que está no `data`

Comment: Perfeito! Muito bom!

Comment: Já agora, para mudar o nome das "legendas" precisaria de mudar a`query` e alterar em `var data...`?

Comment: Sim. Como não vejo o código onde adicionas essas labels, presumo que seja o valor que tens em `$row["classificacao"]`, o primeiro item dos arrays que passas ao `arrayToDataTable` é a label, o segundo é o valor dessa label